# Validate the schema

Tags: node.js, json-schema-validator, ajv

How can we validate the written schema valid or not .

```
const schema = {
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "add": "string" , "minLenfeffgth": 3, "maxLefngth": 255 }
  }
};
```

above mention schema are valid schema according to `ajv.validateSchema()` .

like we validating the data , there is any function who validate the schema .

complete code :

```
var Ajv = require('ajv');

var ajv = new Ajv({ allErrors: true});

const schema = {
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "add": "string" , "minLenfeffgth": 3, "maxLefngth": 255 }
  }
};

// console.log(ajv.validateSchema(schema));
var validate = ajv.compile(schema);

test({"foo": ""});

function test(data) {
  var valid = validate(data);
  if (valid) console.log('Valid!');
  else console.log(validate.errors);
}
```

result is : valid

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Ajv to throw errors and use `compile`:

```js
var ajv = new Ajv({
  allErrors: true
});

var schema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    date: {
      type: 'unexisting-type'
    }
  }
};

try {
  var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/6.6.2/ajv.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please have a look : https://gist.github.com/cmaliwal/8c99e68b8b404596753256b356dc8080

Answer (score 0):

> above mention schema are valid schema according to ajv.validateSchema().

It's valid but it validated nothing, if you want to test a simple object with a `foo` mandatory property, you can do something like that :

```js
var ajv = new Ajv({
  allErrors: true
});

var schema = {
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 3,
      "maxLength": 255
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "foo"
  ]
};

try {
  var validate = ajv.compile(schema);
  test({"foo": "" });
} catch (e) {
  console.log("Validate error :" + e.message);
}


function test(data) {
  var valid = validate(data);
  if (valid) {
    console.log('Valid!');
  } else {
    console.log(validate.errors);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/6.6.2/ajv.min.js"></script>
```

Run with data = `{"foo": "" }` return the error message below :

```sh
[
  {
    "keyword": "minLength",
    "dataPath": ".foo",
    "schemaPath": "#/properties/foo/minLength",
    "params": {
      "limit": 3
    },
    "message": "should NOT be shorter than 3 characters"
  }
]
```

Run with data = `{"foo": "abcdef" }` return the message below :

> Valid!